# How to convert long date frmat

Tags: r, date, tidyverse, lubridate

I have  Dataframe with a date in this format

```
"Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:14 GMT+0100"
```

see the data frame below

```
Time                                Account Name    Type    Product ID  Successful
Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:14 GMT+0100   switch  topup   MFIN-1-OR   undefined
Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:14 GMT+0100   switch  topup   MFIN-1-OR   undefined
Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:14 GMT+0100   switch  topup   MFIN-1-OR   undefined
Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:14 GMT+0100   switch  topup   MFIN-1-OR   undefined
Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:12 GMT+0100   switch  topup   MFIN-1-OR   TRUE
Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:12 GMT+0100   switch  topup   MFIN-1-OR   TRUE
Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:11 GMT+0100   switch  topup   MFIN-1-OR   TRUE
Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:11 GMT+0100   switch  topup   MFIN-1-OR   TRUE
Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:11 GMT+0100   switch  topup   MFIN-1-OR   TRUE
Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:10 GMT+0100   switch  topup   MFIN-1-OR   TRUE
Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:10 GMT+0100   switch  topup   MFIN-1-OR   TRUE
```

How do I convert it to something like this format below

```
"%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `strptime`.

```
strftime(strptime('Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:14 GMT+0100',
         '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z'), '%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
)
# [1] "21/12/26 08:10:14"
```

In your data frame:

```
transform(dat, Time=strftime(strptime(Time, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z'), 
                             '%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))
#                Time x y
# 1 21/12/26 08:10:14 1 4
# 2 21/12/26 08:10:14 2 5
# 3 21/12/26 08:10:14 3 6
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Time = c("Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:14 GMT+0100", 
"Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:14 GMT+0100", "Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:14 GMT+0100"
), x = 1:3, y = 4:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be automatically parsed with `parse_date` from `parsedate`

```
library(parsedate)
df1$Time <- format(parse_date(df1$Time), "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

-output

```
> df1
               Time x y
1 21/12/26 08:10:14 1 4
2 21/12/26 08:10:14 2 5
3 21/12/26 08:10:14 3 6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Time = c("Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:14 GMT+0100", 
"Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:14 GMT+0100", "Sun Dec 26 2021 08:10:14 GMT+0100"
), x = 1:3, y = 4:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `mdy_hms` function of `lubridate` package after some tweaking: i.e removing everything before first and after last space:
Thanks to @jay.sf for the data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dat %>% 
  mutate(Time = gsub(" [^ ]*$|^[^ ]* ","",Time,perl=T),
         Time = mdy_hms(Time)) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

```
  Time                    x     y
  <dttm>              <int> <int>
1 2021-12-26 08:10:14     1     4
2 2021-12-26 08:10:14     2     5
3 2021-12-26 08:10:14     3     6
```